# How to update several rows with postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table representing an object:

```
id|field1|field2|field3
--|------|------|------
1 |   b  |  f   |  z
2 |   q  |  q   |  q
```

I want to pass several objects to pg function which will update corresponding rows.
Now I see only one way to do it - to pass a jsonb with array of objects. For example:
`[{"id":1, "field1":"foo", "field2":"bar", "field3":"baz"},{"id":2, "field1":"fooz", "field2":"barz", "field3":"bazz"}]`
Is this a best way to perform an update? And what is the best way to do it with jsonb input?
I don't really like the way to convert jsonb input to rows with `select * from json_each('{"a":"foo", "b":"bar"}')` and operating it. I would prefer some way to execute a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: Please add your table schema, sample data with code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in next way (using [json_populate_recordset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)):

```
update test
set 
    field1 = data.field1,
    field2 = data.field2,
    field3 = data.field3
from (select * from json_populate_recordset(
  NULL::test, 
  '[{"id":1, "field1":"f.1.2", "field2":"f.2.2", "field3":"f.3.2"},{"id":2, "field1":"f.1.4", "field2":"f.2.5", "field3":"f.3.6"}]'
)) data
where test.id = data.id;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9eca797c248fbf4d73891d2cc8b96f77&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 1):

- this can be achieved using `from` clause in `update` along with a **dynamic on the fly table from input** as follows assuming that the DB table and custom input will be mapped/matched with each other on basis of ID

  ```
    update table as t1
    set field1 = custom_input.field1::varchar, 
        field2 = custom_input.field2::varchar, 
        field3 = custom_input.field3::varchar
    from (
        values 
            (1, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'), 
            (2, 'fooz', 'barz', 'bazz')
    ) as custom_input(id, field1, field2, field3) 
    where t1.id = custom_input.id::int;
  ```

Comment: Thx. I'd like to use functions and this cause problems with passing arguments. Now I have same function as you proposed but with `select id, field1, field2, field3 from json_each(in_jsonb)` in from clause. I was wondering if there is a single-line update query with jsonb

Comment: This query is usually executed by dynamically buiding the query at runtime by manipulating strings which is easy to do apart from that it Would be easier to help if you can setup db fiddle with tables and sample data